# Possible to remove leaflet link with image

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am use [leaflet-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) to create map using leaflet.

Is it possible to remove leaflet link and OSM copyright from the map.

I wish to put in leaflet image instead.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

It's probably **not legal** to remove copy-right information, but if you're familiar with javascript search in the leaflet code for

```
'leaflet-control-attribution'
```

Greetings

Comment: @steenhulthin - The attribution control isn't just showing a link; as the question says (" remove ... and OSM copyright"), it includes "Map data (c) OpenStreetMap". Leaving that there is one way to satisfy the *attribution requirement* of whatever map service (e.g. OpenStreetMap) you are using, if any.

Answer (score 48):

When creating the map object, try this:

```
var map = L.map('map', { attributionControl:false });
```

It worked for me

Comment: not working anymore.

Comment: As of 2024 (Leaflet 1.9.4) this solution is working.

Answer (score 12):

A reference to the attribution control instance is being stored in the `attributionControl` property of your `L.Map` instance:

```
var map = new L.Map('map').setView([0, 0], 0);

attribution = map.attributionControl;
```

When you've got that you can use the `setPrefix` method to set a new prefix:

```
attribution.setPrefix('<img src="image.png">');
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-attribution-setprefix

Answer (score 2):

**Simply hide it with CSS**

```css
.leaflet-control-attribution.leaflet-control {
    display: none;
}
```